How do I make a retro pokemon like encounter event in ue5?
So I have an idea for a battle mechanic in a top down 2D game, but that requires me to transition from a top down to a first person view on collision with an enemy. I want it so that the main game is effectively on pause because the main game is time sensitive, but in the meantime I'm basically fighting this dude.
The best way I can describe it is a Pokémon trainer encounter in a retro Pokémon game using only visual scripts. The game is turn based so this analogy translates well.
I just started Unreal like three days ago, I've only managed to make the control systems, how to move and interact etc, but I'm stuck on how to make a transition scene in top down mode, pause the main game, fight this dude in first person, then come back to the game and continuing on in top down mode with the dudes model on the floor because he's an interact-able corpse or something.

Please read the camera documentation for UE5; It describes how to change viewports.
